# Restoring my Tiny Tower progress from Game Center?

Tags: ios, tiny-tower

Game Center says I have 66 floors, but when I go in the game the pop up about restoring my account doesn't appear.

I'm already logged into my Game Center and have tried:

- Uninstalling and reinstalling the app (countless attempts)
- Force Killing the application, but it didn't help.
- Looked at FAQs about restoring back my floors

I'm on iOS if it helps.

Comment: Hi Lugia, what is 'basically almost everything'? Have you tried Force Killing the application? Uninstalling/reinstalling? Manually removing game files?

Comment: I have uninstalled and reinstalled the app for countless attempts. Ive tried force killing the application too, but it didnt help. What do you mean by manually removing the game files?

Comment: Generally an app will store it's data files locally, which should be (but may not be) removed when the app is uninstalled. This is on Android at least, I am not sure about other platforms.

Comment: I'm on iOS and i've looked at FAQs about restoring back my floors. None helped.

Comment: Ok, well I'm not sure what's causing the issue, but I've added the relevant info to your question, hopefully someone has come across this issue before.